# Get JSON response from Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

I want to get `JSON` response from `Web API` Call. I am calling it like below

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myapi.proj.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic TUNTRTpNQ1MhZTIwMTc=");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ClientURL", "http://123.com");
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/name/", priceRequest).Result;
```

I am unable to `JSON` in response variable. I want to get `JSON` response and assign it to my `class` which is somewhat like below

```
public class Information
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string address{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself

This is what i used

```
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var test = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Information obj = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Information>();
```

You need to reference `System.Net.Http.Formatting` assembly where extension method `ReadAsAsync<T>` is defined.

Comment: i am using VS 2013

Comment: How it relates to my answer? :)

Comment: Probably your method is not async. I also see that you call client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/name/", priceRequest).Result instead of await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/name/", priceRequest). It's a bad practice. Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: which Library to add to use await?

Comment: It's a native C# construct. Check the article from above comment too learn basics of async programming in c#.

Comment: For quick check you can avoid async call for this moment: Information obj = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Information>().Result; But again, it's a very bad practice.

Comment: i cannot get to response.content? can you give me correct way to Call web api

Comment: Also await doesnt look like native c#. I have VS 2013 so i think i need to have some library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158668/discussion-between-happy-and-codefuller).

Comment: Consider upgrading @Happy. VS 2013 is REALLY old.

Comment: @MEMark i wish i could